# fancyhdr and chapter*

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using `fancydr` like this:

```
\usepackage{titlesec} % Normal chapter titles
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\emph{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\nouppercase{\emph{\rightmark}}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{}} 
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
```

This doesn't work well with `chapter*{}`, as it leaves the last chapter's details to the header.

e.g. I have

```
\chapter{Conclusions and future directions}
\input{./tex/conclusions}

\chapter*{Summary}
\input{./tex/summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
```

Then the pages in summary show `Conclusions and future directions` in their header. How could I make `fancyhdr` work with `chapter*`? and is there a possibility to disable the `fancyhdr` for some pages?

Comment: Add also `\chaptermark{Summary}` besides the `\addcontentsline` command.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, almost perfect, but is there a way to remove the number in front of the title in header. e.g. I currently get ``0. Abbrevations and Symbols``, but I'd like just ``Abbrevations and Symbols``. the alternative, which might even be better is to disable ``fancyhdr`` for some pages, is this possible?

Comment: [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) discourages the use of starred versions of sectional units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define `\chaptermark` in a better way:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
      \thechapter.\space
    \fi
    #1%
  }{}%
}
```

so “0.” will not be added when the chapter number is zero (that is, for the chapters before the first).

For the conclusion, use

```
\chapter*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}\markboth{Summary}{}
\input{./tex/summary}
```

Notice the different order, because you want to execute those commands at the start of the chapter text, not at the end.

Comment: When I try to redefine the chaptermark, I get the error: ``! Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.``. In the ``fancyhdr`` definition I also have a ``\renewcommand`` for ``\chaptermark``, maybe I could add something to that?

Comment: I see no mention of `\titlesec` in the question. My feeling is that you're adding the `\renewcommand` in a wrong place.

Comment: I added the ``titlesec`` header in the question. When I put your ``\renewcommand{\chaptermark}`` after the ``fancyhdr`` stuff, I get the error, but before that I won't get the error and it doesn't do anything (gets overwritten by the ``fancyhdr`` redefinition of ``chaptermark``, see the OP)

Comment: @Shepherd Sorry, I forgot a `\markboth`! Note that `\markboth` should be used for the summary (not `\chaptermark`).